# Cakephp 3 - Routes being either an action or a parameter

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x

I would like to know how to route the following scenario: I have a controller called Users, in this controller I have many actions, one of those is "profile".

I want my address being like that: mysite.com/users/NameOfTheUser OR  mysite.com/users/edit-profile OR mysite.com/users/edit-photo, etc.

When you go for "edit-profile" you will be redirected to the edit_profile action, but here goes the trick, when you go to "NameOfTheUser" I want to redirect to the "profile" action, passing "NameOfTheUser" as a parameter.

Is there a way to do so without routing every action manually?

**EDIT**
I used the code that Yosi Azwan said, it works but I have to create a new route for each other page in the controller users.

```
Router::connect( '/users/:name', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'profile'], ['pass' => ['name']] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
Router::connect( '/users/:name', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'profile'], ['pass' => ['name']] );
```

and read this for complete documentations  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of what I needed. But for exemple, to go to users/edit I had to create a new route to this action. Without the route it will redirect to the action profile.

But it is working, thx